# Stuck in For loop iteration of index 5 using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, logic

I'm building Connect Four per my beginner's project for the course I'm taking. I can't get it to move on past index 5. It seems to still return true that index 5 is undefined, even though after I click it the first time, it has turned red. I thought it would, per following click, run the for loop, starting with 5 again, but that it would then return False, and go back to the next index, 4, checking that one, and so forth. I have looked up a lot and I am just stuck. I can't figure it out.

I know that the code is not complete for the long run of the game; I'm just trying to understand this step, however ugly the code might be, so that I can move on to another piece.

```
    var gClass = $(".G")

function returnBackgroundColor(rowIndex,colIndex){
  // console.log($(colIndex[rowIndex]).prop("background-color"));
  // console.log(rowIndex);
  return($(colIndex[rowIndex]).prop("background-color"));
}

function changeColor(row, someClass){
  someClass.eq(row).css("background-color","red");
}

function checkColor(someClass){
  someClass.click(function() {
    for (var row = 5; row > -1; row--) {
      if (returnBackgroundColor(row, someClass) === undefined){
        console.log(row);
        return changeColor(row, someClass);
      }else {
        console.log("False");
      }
    }
  })
}

checkColor(gClass)
```

Comment: I have read around, but can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

I understand that the for loop is going to iterate through each element, and that's probably my issue. I thought that using the row index (??) would individualize each element, and I think I have it written out correctly. I'm just not sure how to only deal with the first element that meets the if requirements, and then stop.

I'm assuming that using a return for row and assigning that to a variable before I execute the .css change is a way to go, but I wanted to see what you guys thought before I moved ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through all your elements with `.G` class name every time they are clicked, try using the jQuery `$(this)` keyword inside your click function. Like this:

```
function addClickListener(someClass){
   $(someClass).each(function () {
      this.addEventListener('click', function() {
          // an example of how you use the $(this) 
          $(this).addClass('background-color-red');
      });
  });​
}
```

This way, you will get rid of that for loop and your problem with their index.