# How do I make this continue iteration through the FOR loop. Stuck on index 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, iteration, logic

I'm building Connect Four per my beginner's project for the course I'm taking. I can't get it to move on past index 5. It seems to still return true that index 5 is undefined, even though after I click it the first time, it has turned red. I thought it would, per following click, run the for loop, starting with 5 again, but that it would then return False, and go back to the next index, 4, checking that one, and so forth. I have looked up a lot and I am just stuck. I can't figure it out.

I know that the code is not complete for the long run of the game; I'm just trying to understand this step, however ugly the code might be, so that I can move on to another piece.

```
    var gClass = $(".G")

function returnBackgroundColor(rowIndex,colIndex){
  // console.log($(colIndex[rowIndex]).prop("background-color"));
  // console.log(rowIndex);
  return($(colIndex[rowIndex]).prop("background-color"));
}

function changeColor(row, someClass){
  someClass.eq(row).css("background-color","red");
}

function checkColor(someClass){
  someClass.click(function() {
    for (var row = 5; row > -1; row--) {
      if (returnBackgroundColor(row, someClass) === undefined){
        console.log(row);
        return changeColor(row, someClass);
      }else {
        console.log("False");
      }
    }
  })
}

checkColor(gClass)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck in For loop iteration of index 5 using javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665732/stuck-in-for-loop-iteration-of-index-5-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use increment instead of decrement. And it is better to use dynamic endpoint in the loop

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `return changeColor(row, someClass);`, here you are returning from the function overall. and ending the for loop.

If you want to go to the next index just use `continue`, but this isn't necessary since your scope is already done

```js
for(let i =0; i < 5; i++)
for (var row = 5; row > -1; row--) {
  if (returnBackgroundColor(row, someClass) === undefined){
    console.log(row);
    changeColor(row, someClass);
  } else {
    console.log("False");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `.prop` in your `returnBackgroundColor` function. `$.prop` returns html properties and will not work directly on styles. You may try something like this to compare against instead: `$(colIndex[rowIndex]).css('background-color')`